# Between replication bidirectional Progress Database and Sql Server

Tags: database-replication, progress-db

We have progress db and sql server. But I want bidirectional  replication process between sql server and progress db. I found pro2 tool but this tool is unidirectional and only replication process is worked from progress db to sql server

Answer (score -1):

[SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.org)  (Open Source) supports bidirectional sync between SQL Server and Postgres.   There is also a [SymmetricDS Professional](http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview) version that comes with a web based user interface to setup and maintain your scenario with support included.